# Ir para a "home" da página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como posso fazer através de uma função do javascript, que seja ativado o comando "Home", ou seja, a página dar um salto para o topo da mesma?
Exemplo: Um botão que é clicado e está no fim da página, redireciona o *overflow* para o ínico (topo).

Comment: Vc pode fazer isso apenas com HTML usando Ancoras. https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/html/29_criando-ncoras-em-suas-p-ginas só vai precisar de JS se quiser fazer o BTN aparecer em determinado ponto do Scroll ou que o efeito do Scroll seja suave ou progressivo algo assim

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim com `jQuery`

```js
var body = $("html, body");

$('button').click(function(){
  body.stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, 500, 'swing', function() { 
  
});
})
```

```css
p{
  margin-top: 500px;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>OiM</p>

<button>Voltar</button>
```